# Add arrows to sorted colums

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this tutorial on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp
. Basically shows you how to sort a table by clicking the headers.

However, it doesn't have a feature I want, directional arrows on the column that is being sorted.

I have the CSS:

```
.table-sortable th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-sortable .th-sort-asc::after {
  content: "\25b4";
}

.table-sortable .th-sort-desc::after {
  content: "\25be";
}

.table-sortable .th-sort-asc::after,
.table-sortable .th-sort-desc::after {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.table-sortable .th-sort-asc,
.table-sortable .th-sort-desc {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

My problem is adding the different classes when the `th` is clicked, changing them when clicked again, and remove when clicking a different column.

JS from w3:

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
  switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and make a [mcve]

Comment: So w3schools is not a great resource. The code you posted does not sort columns. but why reinvent the wheel. There are hundreds of loose sorting scripts and tens of frameworks that do what you need without you having to do any coding